# Sobolev interpolation inequality for relatively compact subdomains

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

I was looking at Nicolaescu's *Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds* (3rd edition). In Theorem 10.2.29 he presents (without proof) the following inequality:

For $m \geq 1, p \geq 1, 0 < r \leq R$ there exists a $C > 0$ s.t. for every $j < m, \epsilon >0$ and $ u \in W^{m, p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ supported on $B_R$:
\begin{equation}
    \| u \|_{j, p, \mathbb{R}^n} \leq C \left( \epsilon \|u\|_{m, p, \mathbb{R}^n} + \epsilon^{-j/(m-j)} \|u\|_{0, p, B_r} \right)
\end{equation}
Note that the last norm is taken over $B_r$, not $B_R$.
(Actually the book says "$\epsilon^{-j(m-j)}$" in the second summand but believe this is a mistake. There is also some talk about picking cutoff functions but I don't think that's relevant to the main point.)

The author references Adams and Fournier's book on Sobolev spaces for a proof. Indeed Theorem 5.12 of that book is a very similar result: For a sufficiently nice open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ it gives a bound
\begin{equation}
    \| u \|_{j, p, \Omega} \leq C \left( \epsilon \| u\|_{m, p, \Omega} + \epsilon^{-j/(m-j)} \|u\|_{0, p, \Omega_\epsilon}\right)
\end{equation}

for $u \in W^{m, p}(\Omega)$. However here $\Omega_\epsilon$ is only some mystery subset of $\Omega$ whose closure lies in $\Omega$ and which depends on $\epsilon$.

My question is how/if you can get the first inequality from the second given that the second one offers no control on $\Omega_\epsilon$.

Comment: I've moved this question from math.stackexchange (and deleted the question there).

Comment: I am slightly confused, the proof of the first inequality (Nicolaescu version) points to the second inequality (Adams/Fournier book), yet you ask how to to get the second inequality from the first. Is that a mix up or actually the correct question?

Comment: @Hannes Oh that's a mistake, thanks for pointing it out. I fixed it.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but since $u$ is assumed to be supported in $B_R$, the $\mathbb{R}^n$ norms are the same as $B_R$ norms, and in the quoted theorem, the $\Omega_\varepsilon$ norm is surely bounded by the $\Omega$ norm, so with $\Omega = B_R$ this is it?

Comment: The first inequality has a $r$, not $R$ in the last term. Nicolaescu is basically claiming that the $(j, p)$-norm is controlled  by $\epsilon$ times the $(m, p)$ norm plus $\epsilon^{...}$ times the norm on **any** compact subdomain. The result from Adams-Fournier only says **some** compact subdomain which might even depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah, that makes it more complicated :-) Sorry for not reading carefully enough.

Comment: But this cannot be true as stated. Take a smooth function supported in $B_R \setminus B_r$ so that $\|u\|_{0,p, B_r}=0$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$; then you get that $u=0$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune It seems like you're right. I feel quite stupid now for noticing that earlier.